# I'm getting wired error when trying to connect PDF.js to my LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, opportunity, js, parsing, opportunity-teams

I'm doing a little project - the idea is, I am given Invoice pdf file and I have to parse that to JSON so that I could insert invoice data into Opportunity and OpportunityLineItem. I'm using PDF.js library to get the text data from my pdf file. But at the moment I'm calling a function from PDF.js, in asynchronous way my app crushes. Here is the screenshot with console logs where you can see the error and the source code. If you had similar problem I will be thankful for your help![image: error log]

**invoiceParser.html**

```
<template>
<lightning-card title="Invoice Uploader">
    <lightning-file-upload
            name="fileUploader"
            record-id={recordId}
            onuploadfinished={handleUploadFinished}
            accept={acceptedFormats}
            multiple="false">
    </lightning-file-upload>
</lightning-card>
```

**invoiceParser.js**

```
import {LightningElement, api} from 'lwc';
import {ShowToastEvent} from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import pdf from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/pdf";
import pdfWorker from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/pdfWorker';
import {loadScript} from "lightning/platformResourceLoader";

export default class InvoiceParser extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    originalFile;

    connectedCallback() {
        Promise.all([loadScript(this, pdf), loadScript(this, pdfWorker)])
            .then(() => {
                console.log('pdfjs loaded');
                pdfjsLib.workerSrc = pdfWorker;
                this.getItems(this.originalFile);
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(`Error loading scripts: ${error}`);
        })
    }

    get acceptedFormats() {
        return [".pdf"];
    }

    handleUploadFinished(event) {
        this.originalFile = event.detail.files[0];
        console.log('originalFile --- ', this.originalFile);
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                title: "Successes",
                message: `${this.originalFile.name} uploaded successfully.`,
                variant: 'successes'
            })
        );
    }

    async getContent(src) {
        const doc = await pdfjsLib.getDocument(src);
        const page = await doc.getPage(1);
        return await page.getTextContent();
    }

    async getItems(src) {
        const content = await this.getContent(src);
        return content.items.map((item) => item.str);
    }
}
```

**Metadata**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>55.0</apiVersion>
    <description>Invoice Parser</description>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <masterLabel>Invoice Parser</masterLabel>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to security concerns regarding Worker scripts (Worker, SharedWorker, and ServiceWorkerContainer), these features are disabled by both Locker Service and Lightning Web Security. Any scripts that rely on these features won't work. PDF.js appears to have intentionally forced workers to be used for performance reasons unless running in Node, so as written, it won't be compatible inside of Salesforce. You'll have to either modify the source to not use a worker, or use an alternative library.

Comment: Ok then, thank you so much for info :)